# How to split content below every h3 with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, split, css-selectors

I have a peace of html that looks like this:

```
<h3>PETIT DEJEUNER</h3>
<p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>

<h3>AUTRE PETIT DEJEUNER</h3>
<p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>

<h3>AND ONE MORE DEJEUNER</h3>
<p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>
<p>CROISSANT</p>
```

Of course the contents vary. Unfortunately I do not control the html, it is delivered from another source. Can I split the content at every h3, creating a collection like this:

```
menu = [
    {
        title: 'PETIT DEJEUNER',
        contents: [<p contents>,<p contents>,<pcontents>]
    },
    {
        title: 'AUTRE PETIT DEJEUNER',
        contents: [<p contents>,<p contents>,<pcontents>]
    },
]
```

I'm using jQuery. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can combine [nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to match the paragraphs between `<h3>` elements, and use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to build your arrays:

```
var menu = $("h3").map(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return {
        title: $this.text(),
        contents: $this.nextUntil("h3").filter("p").map(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        }).get();
    };
}).get();
```

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for! Tnx!

Answer (score 3):

```
var menu = [];

$("<h3>PETIT DEJEUNER</h3><p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p><p>CROISSANT</p><p>CROISSANT</p><h3>AUTRE PETIT DEJEUNER</h3><p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p><p>CROISSANT</p><p>CROISSANT</p><h3>AND ONE MORE DEJEUNER</h3><p>FRANS ONTBIJT</p><p>CROISSANT</p><p>CROISSANT</p>")
    .filter('h3')
    .each(function() {
        menu.push({
                   title: $(this).text(),
                   contents: $(this).nextUntil('h3').map(function() {
                                 return $(this).text();
                             }).get()
                  });
     });
```